# Firefox transform: rotate breaks text color

Tags: css, firefox, rotation

I have constructed the following CSS (from various sources) to create a Post-it note and is using it within a LayerSlider banner animation. It works correctly if **not rotated**, but it either loses text color or blink from white to set color in Firefox when "transform: rotate(5deg);" option is added. I've tried some of the suggested solutions listed online, but no success. Works 100% in most other browsers.

```
.orange {
text-align:center;
width: 350px;
margin: 15px;
min-height:175px;
max-height:175px;
padding-top:15px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid #FFDC73;
font-family:'Handlee';
font-size:22px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 5px;
display:inline-block;
box-shadow: 16px 21px 21px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
background: #FFCD5A; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFCD5A 81%, #FFCD5A 82%, #FFCD5A
82%, #ffebc0 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
color-stop(81%,#FFCD5A), color-stop(82%,#FFCD5A), color-stop(82%,#FFCD5A),
color-stop(100%,#ffebc0)); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFCD5A 81%,#FFCD5A 82%,#FFCD5A 
82%,#ffebc0 100%); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFCD5A 81%,#FFCD5A 82%,#FFCD5A 
82%,#ffebc0 100%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFCD5A 81%,#FFCD5A 82%,#FFCD5A 
82%,#ffebc0 100%); 
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #FFCD5A 81%,#FFCD5A 82%,#FFCD5A 
82%,#ffebc0 100%); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
startColorstr='#FFCD5A', endColorstr='#ffebc0',GradientType=1 ); 
}
```

I am using this to rotate the note:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
-o-transform: rotate(5deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
transform: rotate(5deg);
```

adding something like "translateZ(0) " does not improve the reslult

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by splitting the CSS style into two parts, one for the note (style that is common to all colours) and the second part for the note’s colour option.  Subsequent slides in LayerSlider do not lose their text colour now.
Also the “Use hardware acceleration when available” option in Firefox influence the behaviour of this in my first attempt.

```
.note {
            text-align:center;
            width: 350px;
            margin: 15px;
            min-height:175px;
            max-height:175px;
            padding-top:15px;
            position:relative;
            font-family:'Handlee';
            color: #131304;
            font-size:22px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 5px;
            display:inline-block;
            box-shadow: 16px 21px 21px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) rotate(5deg);
            -moz-transform: translateZ(0) rotate(5deg);
            -o-transform: translateZ(0) rotate(5deg);
            -ms-transform: translateZ(0) rotate(5deg);
            transform: translateZ(0) rotate(5deg);
        }

.orange {
            border:1px solid #FFDB8D;
            background: #FFCD5A; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFCD5A 81%, #FFCD5A 82%, #FFCD5A 82%, #ffebc0 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(81%,#FFCD5A), color-stop(82%,#FFCD5A), color-stop(82%,#FFCD5A), color-stop(100%,#ffebc0)); 
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFCD5A 81%,#FFCD5A 82%,#FFCD5A 82%,#ffebc0 100%); 
            background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFCD5A 81%,#FFCD5A 82%,#FFCD5A 82%,#ffebc0 100%); 
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFCD5A 81%,#FFCD5A 82%,#FFCD5A 82%,#ffebc0 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, #FFCD5A 81%,#FFCD5A 82%,#FFCD5A 82%,#ffebc0 100%); 
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFCD5A', endColorstr='#ffebc0',GradientType=1 ); 

        }
```